# Problems making a booking into local database in VB 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi I am currently trying to sore details about a lesson in a local .mdf database, but do not seem to be able to do so, I have had this problem for a few weeks and really need to sort it out so any help would be much appreciated. 
I will include my code for the form below.
Thanks in advance for your help!!

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Session As String
    Session = txtSession.text

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim inscmd As New SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
            con.Open()

            Dim ParamInitial As New SqlParameter
            ParamInitial.ParameterName = ("@StaffInitials")
            ParamInitial.Value = lblStaffInitials.Text.Trim()
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamInitial)

            Dim ParamWeek As New SqlParameter
            ParamWeek.ParameterName = ("@Week")
            ParamWeek.Value = lblWeek.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamWeek)

            Dim ParamPeriod As New SqlParameter
            ParamPeriod.ParameterName = ("@Period")
            ParamPeriod.Value = lblPeriod.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamPeriod)

            Dim ParamDay As New SqlParameter
            ParamDay.ParameterName = ("@Day")
            ParamDay.Value = lblDay.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamDay)

            Dim ParamSubject As New SqlParameter
            ParamSubject.ParameterName = ("@Subject")
            ParamSubject.Value = lblSubject.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamSubject)

            Dim ParamYearGroup As New SqlParameter
            ParamYearGroup.ParameterName = ("@YearGroup")
            ParamYearGroup.Value = lblYear.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamYearGroup)

            Dim ParamNumberPupils As New SqlParameter
            ParamNumberPupils.ParameterName = ("@NumberOfPupils")
            ParamNumberPupils.Value = lblNoOfPupils.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamNumberPupils)

            Dim ParamControlledAssesment As New SqlParameter
            ParamControlledAssesment.ParameterName = ("@ControlledAssesment")
            ParamControlledAssesment.Value = lblControlledAssesment.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamControlledAssesment)

            Dim ParamRoom As New SqlParameter
            ParamRoom.ParameterName = ("@Room")
            ParamRoom.Value = lblRoom.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamRoom)

            Dim ParamSession As New SqlParameter
            ParamSession.ParameterName = ("@Session")
            ParamSession.Value = txtSession.Text.Trim
            inscmd.Parameters.Add(ParamSession)

            inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking (Week, Day, Period, Subject, YearGroup, StaffInitials, NumberOfPupils, Session, Room, ControlledAssesment)VALUES (@Week,@Day,@Period,@Subject,@YearGroup,@StaffInitials,@NumberOfPupils,@Session,@Room,@ControlledAssesment)"
            'inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking (Week, Day, Period, Subject, YearGroup, StaffInitials, NumberOfPupils, Session, Room, ControlledAssesment)VALUES ('B','Monday',5,'Politics','U6','JAGG',5,'5','LIT','False')"
            Print(inscmd.CommandText)
            inscmd.Connection = con
            inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            inscmd.Parameters.Clear()
        End Using
        ' Catch ex As Exception
        '   MsgBox("" & ex.Message)
        'if there is an error it will go here (can use Msgbox or label)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    MsgBox("Your Booking Has Been Made Successfully")
    Clicky = False
    MainViewForm.btnBackToBooking.Visible = False
    FormView.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get? Any error message - pls provide some additional information

Comment: With the current setup I get this error (Sorry for not adding to begin with) 

Conversion from string "INSERT INTO Booking (Week, Day, " to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: Did you try setting SqlDbType?

Comment: If this error occurs within `inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking ...` you should really try setting **SqlDbType** ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) )as Bulat mentions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the problem lies within the databases location.

When the program is debugged a **copy of your database** is placed within the bin/debug folder, if you look in here you will see the copy and your code will right to this database and **Not The original Database** *(if you click show all files then go to the bin/debug file and then open with database explorer you can see the data imputed on the last debug/running)*

To fix this you need to do the following:

Your connection string

```
 con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
```

Will connect to the database within the bin folder mentioned previously.

You need to go into your **app.config** file find the specific location for your database and use this for you connection string, this will allow you to insert/update data from the non copy of the database.

Answer (score 1):

I see two insert command in your example above. The commented out command shows two values treated as numbers and not as strings.
You use the command text that use parameters, but all of the prepared parameters are set to the string datatype (well you don't set any datatype and this defaults the DbType property to NVarChar)
Probably this is the exact error message you get when executing the insert command

You could try the following:

```
   Using cn As New SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWitValue("@StaffInitials", lblStaffInitials.Text.Trim())
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Week", lblWeek.Text.Trim)
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", Convert.ToInt32(lblPeriod.Text.Trim))
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day",lblDay.Text.Trim)
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", lblSubject.Text.Trim)
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearGroup", lblYear.Text.Trim)
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfPupils", Convert.ToInt32(lblNoOfPupils.Text.Trim))
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlledAssesment", lblControlledAssesment.Text.Trim)
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room",lblRoom.Text.Trim)
        inscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Session", txtSession.Text.Trim)

        inscmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking ([Week], [Day], [Period], [Subject], " +
                             "[YearGroup], [StaffInitials],[NumberOfPupils],[Session], " + 
                             "[Room],[ControlledAssesment]) "+
                             "VALUES " + 
                             "(@Week,@Day,@Period,@Subject,@YearGroup,@StaffInitials," +
                             "@NumberOfPupils,@Session,@Room,@ControlledAssesment)"
        inscmd.Connection = con
        inscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        inscmd.Parameters.Clear()
    End Using
```

I have use the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to implicitly create a parameter with a `DbType` property that is derived from the value added. So if I add a string as value,  the parameter will have a `DbType.NVarchar`, but if I set an integer the DbType will be `DbType.Int`. Of course this assumes that all of your field above are of NVarChar type except `Period` and `NumberOfPupils`. If this is not true you should add the appropriate conversion to the parameter

EDIT: Not sure, but I suspect also that DAY is a reserved keyword. Better to encapsulate the column names with square brackets

Comment: This solved the problem with the conversion error but unfortunatly doesn't solve the problem that the program does not yet actually insert into the Booking table.. any suggestions are welcome and I look forward to more help from you amazing people :D

Comment: Do you have any error? Are you sure that your connection string is pointing to the right database? Could you show that string?

Comment: There are no errors being recorded, the connection string is correct (used in other code), the connection string is below.
`       connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString`

Comment: I have asked about the connection string because I wish to know if you use the AttachDbFileName option with an MDF file listed in your solution files. Sometime this result in the wrong database updated. (Look for Copy to Output Directory set to Copy Always on the MDF properties)

Comment: Have checked this as requested and the Copy to Output Directory was already set to Copy Always on the MDF properties

Comment: At that's the error. Let me explain what I think it is happening. If you have `copy always` for the MDF file and use the `AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\file.mdf` connection string, your update goes to the database sitting in the so called `datadirectory` (usually a bin\debug subfolder of your project folder). Then you stop the debugging session, change/fix something and then restart the session. At this point a fresh copy of your MDF file **without the last changes** is copied over the one in the bin\debug folder. You should set that property to `copy never` or `copy if newer`

Comment: I have tried both of the aforementioned instances without success, while using `copy never` get an error message saying that `"An attempt to attach an auto-named database file for C:\Users\...\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\Databse1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.`

Comment: A quick search for your error message shows that there are numerous situations in which you could get that error. A previous database with the same file name? Invalid permissions for the ASP.NETservice? Difficult to say, I can only suggest to check for the obvious one (A different database with the same MDF file name)

Comment: In the file path mentioned in the error message there are two database related files... `Database1` a sql Sever database  primary data file and `Database1_log` a sql server transaction log file.